# Error: `siteUrl` does not exist on `siteMetadata` in the data returned from the query. How to resolve?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, sitemap

When building my Gatsby website I get the below error.
I've tried to delete and reinstall npm, update the plugins, deleting (Gatsby) cache, playing around with the siteUrl and all kinds of settings in the Gatsby config. But I can't seem to get rid of the error. The development environment works fine.

github: https://github.com/bartfluitsma/gatsby-bart-fluitsma

```
**Error console log**

ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-plugin-sitemap" threw an error while running the onPostBuild lifecycle:

`siteUrl` does not exist on `siteMetadata` in the data returned from the query.
Add this to your `siteMetadata` object inside gatsby-config.js or add this to your custom query or provide a custom `resolveSiteUrl` function.
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/#api-reference


  47 |             errors = _yield$graphql.errors;
  48 |             _context.next = 9;
> 49 |             return Promise.resolve(resolveSiteUrl(queryRecords)).catch(function (err) {
     |                                    ^
  50 |               return reporter.panic(_internals.REPORTER_PREFIX + " Error resolving Site URL", err);
  51 |             });
  52 |

File: node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sitemap\gatsby-node.js:49:36



  Error: `siteUrl` does not exist on `siteMetadata` in the data returned from the query.
  Add this to your `siteMetadata` object inside gatsby-config.js or add this to your custom query or provide a custom `resolveSiteUrl` function.
  https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/#api-reference

  - internals.js:62 resolveSiteUrl
    [gatsby-bart-fluitsma]/[gatsby-plugin-sitemap]/internals.js:62:11

  - gatsby-node.js:49 _callee$
    [gatsby-bart-fluitsma]/[gatsby-plugin-sitemap]/gatsby-node.js:49:36


not finished onPostBuild - 0.480s
```

**Gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Bart Fluitsma`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
    siteUrl: `http://bartfluitsma.com`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    'gatsby-plugin-postcss',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts-with-attributes`,
      options: {
        fonts: [
          `montserrat\:300,400,400i,600,900`,
        ],
        display: 'swap',
        attributes: {
          rel: "stylesheet preload prefetch",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    }, {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/locales`,
        name: `locale`
      }
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `Web development | Bart Fluitsma`,
        short_name: `Bart develops`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        // This will impact how browsers show your PWA/website
        // https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/
        // theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/logo-bart-fluitsma-web-design.svg`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next`,
      options: {
        localeJsonSourceName: `locale`, // name given to `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin.
        languages: [`en`, `nl`],
        defaultLanguage: `en`,
        // if you are using Helmet, you must include siteUrl, and make sure you add http:https
        siteUrl: `https://bartfluitsma.com`,
        // you can pass any i18next options
        i18nextOptions: {
          interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
          },
          keySeparator: false,
          nsSeparator: false
        },
        pages: [
          {
            matchPath: '/:lang?/blog/:uid',
            getLanguageFromPath: true
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
      options: {
        excludes: ['/**/404', '/**/404.html'],
        query: `
            {
              site {
                siteMetadata {
                  siteUrl
                }
              }
              allSitePage(filter: {context: {i18n: {routed: {eq: false}}}}) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    context {
                      i18n {
                        defaultLanguage
                        languages
                        originalPath
                      }
                    }
                    path
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          `,
        serialize: ({ site, allSitePage }) => {
          return allSitePage.edges.map((edge) => {
            const { languages, originalPath, defaultLanguage } = edge.node.context.i18n;
            const { siteUrl } = site.siteMetadata;
            const url = siteUrl + originalPath;
            const links = [
              { lang: defaultLanguage, url },
              { lang: 'x-default', url }
            ];
            languages.forEach((lang) => {
              if (lang === defaultLanguage) return;
              links.push({ lang, url: `${siteUrl}/${lang}${originalPath}` });
            });
            return {
              url,
              changefreq: 'daily',
              priority: originalPath === '/' ? 1.0 : 0.7,
              links
            };
          });
        }
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the cache with `gatsby clean`?

Comment: Thanks for your message Ferran. Yes, I've cleaned the Gatsby cache multiple times, but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is thrown by `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`. Try adding the `resolveSiteUrl` method in your configuration like:

```
const siteUrl = process.env.URL || `https://fallback.net`

resolveSiteUrl: () => siteUrl,
```

Applied to your code:

```
const siteUrl = process.env.URL || `https://fallback.net`

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sitemap",
      options: {
        excludes: ["/**/404", "/**/404.html"],
        query: `
            {
              site {
                siteMetadata {
                  siteUrl
                }
              }
              allSitePage(filter: {context: {i18n: {routed: {eq: false}}}}) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    context {
                      i18n {
                        defaultLanguage
                        languages
                        originalPath
                      }
                    }
                    path
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          `,
        resolveSiteUrl: () => siteUrl,
        serialize: ({ site, allSitePage }) => {
          return allSitePage.edges.map((edge) => {
            const { languages, originalPath, defaultLanguage } =
              edge.node.context.i18n;
            const { siteUrl } = site.siteMetadata;
            const url = siteUrl + originalPath;
            const links = [
              { lang: defaultLanguage, url },
              { lang: "x-default", url },
            ];
            languages.forEach((lang) => {
              if (lang === defaultLanguage) return;
              links.push({ lang, url: `${siteUrl}/${lang}${originalPath}` });
            });
            return {
              url,
              changefreq: "daily",
              priority: originalPath === "/" ? 1.0 : 0.7,
              links,
            };
          });
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Change the `siteUrl` and the fallback URL accordingly if you are not setting it in your environment file

Comment: Thank you! It seems that it resolves the issue regarding the siteUrl. But it throws me the following errors: 

Field "context" is not defined by type "SitePageFilterInput"
and
GraphQLError: Cannot query field "context" on type "SitePage"

Seems to have something to do with the query of the i18n. Is this resolved in a similar matter?

Comment: This is an issue in your query now, in `allSitePage`. Check the query in the GraphiQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`)

Comment: Thanks Ferran! Yes, it's the next challenge I need to deal with :)

Comment: @Bart so the `context` prop on the query is invalid. Most likely replacement seems `pageContext`. Have you figured it out and can share the solution?

Comment: @bebbi thank you for your message. My solution was to start over, with the code above (I could do so because I was at the beginning of the project and trying it out). But I see a new answer below, hope that works.

Answer (score 3):

[The answer by Ferran Buireu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72256872/5211833) ultimately was not the solution for OP. I had experienced the same issue and this solution would have solved his issue hadn't he abandoned it. Check this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/microapps/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/issues/143#issuecomment-1219277484).

Your `siteUrl` issue just masks that the query was invalid, as the `context` is not available in gatsby >= 4 anymore, as you found out after fixing the `siteUrl`.

You may have used this query from the [gatsby-plugin-react-i18next](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/) docs to support a sitemap.

In order to make it work, I found you have to 1. create the context yourself, and 2. adjust the queries

1. Create your context through `gatsby-node.js` (credit [wilsonvolker](https://github.com/microapps/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/issues/143#issuecomment-1183523819))

```js
/**
 * Workaround for missing sitePage.context:
 * Used for generating sitemap with `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next` and `gatsby-plugin-sitemap` plugins
 * https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v3-to-v4/#field-sitepagecontext-is-no-longer-available-in-graphql-queries
 */
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
    const { createTypes } = actions
    createTypes(`
    type SitePage implements Node {
      context: SitePageContext
    }
    type SitePageContext {
      i18n: i18nContext
    }
    type i18nContext {
        language: String,
        languages: [String],
        defaultLanguage: String,
        originalPath: String
        routed: Boolean
    }
  `)
}
```

2. It looks like the `serialize` function proposed in the i18next doesn't work as-is anymore since it apparently receives a single node, not the full graphql response. So, a few changes in `gatsby-config.js` to make it work again (this assumes you have a global `siteUrl` variable available):

```js
query: `
  {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        siteUrl
      }
    }
    allSitePage(filter: {context: {i18n: {routed: {eq: false}}}}) {
      nodes {
        context {
          i18n {
            defaultLanguage
            languages
            originalPath
          }
        }
        path
      }
    }
  }
`,
serialize: (node) => {
  const { languages, originalPath, defaultLanguage } = node.context.i18n
  const url = siteUrl + originalPath
  const links = [
    { lang: defaultLanguage, url },
    { lang: 'x-default', url },
  ]
  languages.forEach((lang) => {
    if (lang === defaultLanguage) return
    links.push({ lang, url: `${siteUrl}/${lang}${originalPath}` })
  })
  return {
    url,
    changefreq: 'daily',
    priority: originalPath === '/' ? 1.0 : 0.7,
    links,
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me without the need to create new types:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sitemap",
  options: {
    excludes: ["/**/404", "/**/404.html"],
    resolveSiteUrl: () => siteUrl,
    query: `
      {
        allSitePage {
          edges {
            node {
              pageContext
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    resolvePages: ({ allSitePage: { edges } }) => {
      return edges
        .filter(
          ({ node }) => !["/404/", "/404.html"].includes(node.pageContext.i18n.originalPath)
        )
        .map(({ node: { pageContext } }) => {
          const { languages, originalPath, path, defaultLanguage } = pageContext.i18n;
          const baseUrl = siteUrl + originalPath;
          const links = [{ lang: "x-default", url: baseUrl }];

          languages.forEach((lang) => {
            const isDefaultLang = lang === defaultLanguage;
            const isDefaultPath = path === originalPath;
            const isLangSubDir = path.includes(`${lang}/`);

            if (isDefaultLang && isDefaultPath) return;
            if (!isDefaultLang && isLangSubDir) return;

            links.push({
              lang,
              url: isDefaultLang ? baseUrl : `${siteUrl}/${lang}${originalPath}`,
            });
          });

          return {
            path,
            url: path === "/" ? siteUrl : `${siteUrl}/${path}`,
            changefreq: "daily",
            priority: originalPath === "/" ? 1.0 : 0.7,
            links,
          };
        });
    },
    serialize: (page) => page,
  },
}
```

Versions:
Node: 18.13.0

```
"gatsby": "^5.3.3",
"gatsby-plugin-react-i18next": "^3.0.1",
"gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^6.5.0",
```

Comment: This works for me too. It is worth noting that pageContext is now a JSON and has no subfields

Answer (score 0):

I'm customizing the code for generating a multilingual sitemap as follows.
In the actual production code, each language in the 'languages' variable is retrieved from the i18n configuration settings.

```js
import type { GatsbyConfig } from 'gatsby'

const languages = ['en', 'fr', 'ja']

const config: GatsbyConfig = {
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-pnpm',
    'gatsby-plugin-postcss',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
      options: {
        excludes: ['/**/404', '/**/404.html'],
        serialize: ({ path }) => {
          // Get the page path without the language code.
          const pagepath = path.replace(/\/.*?\//, '/')
          // Generate XML links for each language.
          const xmlLinks = languages.map((lang: string) => ({
            rel: 'alternate',
            hreflang: lang,
            url: `/${lang}${pagepath}`
          }))
          xmlLinks.push({
            rel: 'alternate',
            hreflang: 'x-default',
            url: `${pagepath}`
          })

          let entry = {
            url: path,
            changefreq: 'daily',
            links: xmlLinks
          }

          return entry
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The generated XML looks as below.

```xml
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>https://sample.com/</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://sample.com/en/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="https://sample.com/ja/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://sample.com/" />
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://sample.com/en/</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://sample.com/en/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="https://sample.com/ja/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://sample.com/" />
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://sample.com/ja/</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://sample.com/en/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="https://sample.com/ja/" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://sample.com/" />
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Versions: Node: v19.4.0

```
"gatsby": "v19.4.0",
"gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "6.11.0"
```